# Parameter is not valid when saving TIFF to stream

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have a multi-page TIFF that I'm splitting up page by page using Leadtools, and changing the compression on them to be compatible with a third party. When I try to save the image to a memoryStream, I get a Parameter is not valid exception. However, this *only* happens on their machine, or my test machine running Server 2008. I cannot reproduce this on my development machine (Win 7 using VS2008). Here is the code:

```
              RasterImage image = codecs.Load( file, 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.RgbOrGray, currentPage, currentPage + (detail.Pages - 1) );
              Image newImage = RasterImageConverter.ConvertToImage( image, ConvertToImageOptions.None );
              MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

              ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = GetEncoderInfo(  );

              EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters( 1 );
              EncoderParameter parameter = new EncoderParameter( System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4 );
              encoderParams.Param[0] = parameter;
              newImage.Save(memStream, encoderInfo , encoderParams);
```

Any thoughts on this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are the architectures on those machines? x86/x64? What version of the .NET framework are you targeting and which version and target environment are you using from LeadTools?

Comment: My dev machine is x64. My test machine is x86. I'm not sure what the customer machine OS or architecture is, unfortunately. The Target framework is 3.5, and the leadtools version is 17.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the pixel format of the image.  If it's anything other than 1 bit, this will fail - you can't use CCITT on anything other than 1 bit.  It could also be that the particular OS doesn't have a CCITT4 subcodec and might only have a CCITT3 (although this is highly unlikely).

Comment: Looks like the pixel format is Format32bppArgb. I assume this won't work when trying to convert it to Group 4? I'm not sure why then, it works on my machine.

Comment: Looks like I can pass a specified bit per pixel argument to the RasterCodec when originally generating the image. This now sets my PixelFormat to  Format1bppIndexed. I'll see how this works on my test machine. Also, I assume you meant 'you can't use CCITT on anything other than 1 bit'

Comment: +1 I had the same problem.  On Win7 it seems to default to LZW instead of throwing an error.